# Does root processor apply MPI_Reduce to itself as well?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

When using `MPI_reduce`, does the root processor apply the specified MPI operation on itself as well?

For example, assume the following code is run by all processors including the root, does root reduce it's `local_sum` into `global_sum` as if it is non-root one?

```
int local_sum;
int global_sum;

int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  local_sum += rand_nums[i];
}

MPI_Reduce(&local_sum, &global_sum, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, ROOT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: If you don't want to use the value from process 0 in the reduction, you can do it by building an intercommunicator, process 0 being the remote leader. See page 293 of [the MPI standards](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf), the documentation of [`MPI_Intercomm_create()`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Intercomm_create.html) and the one of [`MPI_Reduce`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Reduce.3.php), in particular the section `When Communicator is an Inter-communicator`.

Comment: The point is that it is *only* the root process that applies the operation. With Reduce, the answer is *only* stored on the root process, i.e. the values of global_sum on all non-root processes will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, reduce is also applied to the root itself. Maybe in your mind, you think that MPI just add numbers from other ranks to the `local_sum` variable in the root.

However, what MPI actually does is that it reduces from all ranks (including the root) in your communicator and put the result to `global_sum`.

If MPI doesn't reduce the root itself, then it doesn't make sense having two parameters for the MPI_Reduce call.